# Setting default values to table fields inside view web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I'm have the following code for my app:

```
db.define_table('event',
   Field('name'),
   Field('date','date'),
   Field('location'),
   format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('presentations',
   Field('event', db.event),
   Field('title'),
   Field('description'),
   Field('level'))

db.define_table('presenters',
   Field('name'),
   Field('company'),
   Field('resume'), 
   Field('avatar','upload),
   format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('presentations_presenters',
   Field('presentation', db.presentation),
   Field('presenter', db.presenters))
```

Then I have created a controller for presentations:

```
def admpresentations():
    presentationList=db(db.presentations.event==request.vars.eventid).select()
    return dict(presentations=presentationList)
```

and in my view this is shown as:

```
{{for presentation in presentations:}}
    {{=presentation.title}}
    {{=presentation.description}}
    {{=presentation.level}}
{{pass}}
```

Now, here's my question: I have to add presenters for each presentation. For this want to set a default value for `presentations_presenters.presentation`, since there can be more than one presenter for each presentation, so I'm trying this in my view:

```
{{for presentation in presentations:}}
    {{=presentation.title}}
    {{=presentation.description}}
    {{=presentation.level}}

    <!--This is for setting a default value to presentation field, but doesn't work-->
    {{db.presentations_presenters.presentation.default=presentation.id}}


    <!--This creates the form, but default values are ignored-->
    {{=crud.create(db.presentations_presenters}}

{{pass}}
```

tried with SQLFORM, but i can't figure out how to process it in view, so data isn't written into DB... any clues?

### Edit

In last line:

```
    {{=crud.create(db.presentations_presenters}}
```

setting default value does work, but data isn't saved into db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crud.create()` creates a default `_formname` hidden field in the form, which is used in conjunction with the `_formkey` hidden field to protect agains CSRF attacks. Your code ends up creating multiple forms with the same name. As a result, the `_formkey` value stored in the session will match only the last form created, so submissions of any of the earlier forms will be rejected due to a `_formkey` mismatch. To get around this, you must give each form a unique name. For example:

```
{{=crud.create(db.presentations_presenters,
               formname='presenters/%s' % presentation.id)}}
```

Also, if you want to use `SQLFORM` instead, just call the `.process()` method to process it in the view:

```
{{=SQLFORM(db.presentations_presenters).process(
       formname='presenters/%s' % presentation.id)}}
```

Comment: Awesome, this actually works... but i have to refresh page to see new record, which is solved with next=URL()... thank you a lo!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create form in the view?

Simple make a SQLFORM or SQLFORM.factory in the controller and set default values using form.= default value.

Comment: I show the records in the page, and for each record there has a to be a new form to add data based on the curret record and another table, to if I use controllers I can only give one param, and creating the form in the view allows me to set default values for some fields.